# Magento2 : How to override contacts form.phtml in child theme

Tags: magento-2.1.7, contact-form

I want to change page title in child theme for contact-us page. But when I'm trying to override file `Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml` in my child theme from parent theme then on frontend the page showing blank. I also copied `layout/contact_index_index.xml` and all other templates too, still template file overridden not working.

How do I override `Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml`?

My Parent theme `contact_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Namespace\Theme\Block\Template" name="google_map" template="Magento_Contact::google_map.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Theme\Block\Template" name="contactPage" template="Magento_Contact::contact_page.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following things.

create `contact_index_index.xml` at following location.

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[Your Theme]/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml
```

with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm">
           <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Contact::form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Now create form.phtml at following location.

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[Your Theme]/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

Now modify phtml file according to your requirement.

Comment: I tried, but still getting blank page if override. If layout file is in parent theme then it is required to override in child theme too?

Comment: Have you run deploy command after this? also run caching command as well.

Comment: Yes, after deploy command, override file changes showing on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Just overrride the **contact_index_index.xml**  file in your theme by copying the below code at path - **app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_Contact**/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

            <!-- and for the page title: -->
            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
               <action method="setPageTitle">
                  <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your new title</argument>
               </action>
            </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```