# Override form.phtml to customize contact us form?

Tags: magento2.3, forms, contact-form

I am calling the contact form on my CMS page using this (as per [this](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/contact-us.html)):

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm"
 name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

I duplicated:

```
/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

and placed it in my theme folder:

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[my Theme]/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

Cleared caches but the form is still pulling from the core. Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here: [Magento2 : How to override contacts form.phtml in child theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216998/magento2-how-to-override-contacts-form-phtml-in-child-theme)

I need to create the contact_index_index.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

> Your Theme Path
>
> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

Try below code in cms page

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

if not reflects changes on frontend then hit below commands and check

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
```

and also check this one 
[How to call a PHTML file within a CMS page Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85593/how-to-call-a-phtml-file-within-a-cms-page-magento-2/92217)

Comment: if you want to call template in cms page then check my answer